# how to sum up the totals but keep only one name out of multiple

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, reporting-services, sum

I have two `CTE`'s with `ProducerCode`, `ProducerLocationID` and `ProducerName`. But due to the end user's fault the `ProducerName` can be slightly different between those two `CTE`'s. 
How can I have `SUM` grouped by `ProducerCode` and `ProducerLocationID` but keep only one `ProducerName` (lets say from first `CTE`)?

This is what I got now:

[image]
Two rows with `ProducerCode` 1321 and `ProducerLocationID` 1587 need to have `NetWrittenPremium` as  767,109 which is (469956.00 + 297153.00). Same with `WPNewBusiness`  but only have one `ProducerName` as 'The Harry W Gorst Co Inc'

I need it like this:

[image]

Here is my full query :

```
        ;WITH cte_TopWP   --T
AS 
    (
        SELECT  ProducerCode,[Producer Location ID], Producer,
                SUM(premium) as NetWrittenPremium,
                SUM(CASE WHEN PolicyType = 'New Business' THEN Premium ELSE 0 END) as WPNewBusiness,
                SUM(CASE WHEN PolicyType = 'Renewal' THEN Premium ELSE 0 END) as WPRenewal,
                SUM(CASE WHEN PolicyType = 'Rewrite' THEN Premium ELSE 0 END) as WPRewrite, 
                SUM(CASE WHEN PolicyType = 'New Business' AND TransactionType = 'Policy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as BindsNewBusiness,
                SUM(CASE WHEN PolicyType = 'Renewal' AND TransactionType = 'Policy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as BindsRenewals,
                SUM(CASE WHEN PolicyType = 'Rewrite' AND TransactionType = 'Policy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as BindsRewrite,
                SUM(CASE WHEN PolicyType = 'New Business' AND TransactionType = 'Policy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN PolicyType = 'Renewal' AND TransactionType = 'Policy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN PolicyType = 'Rewrite' AND TransactionType = 'Policy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as PolicyCount        
        FROM    ProductionReportMetrics 
        WHERE   EffectiveDate >=DateAdd(yy, -1, DATEADD(d, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE()))) AND EffectiveDate <= EOMONTH(GETDATE()) AND TransactionType = 'Policy' AND CompanyLine = 'Plaza Insurance Company' AND ProducerType = 'Wholesaler'
        GROUP BY ProducerCode,
                [Producer Location ID],Producer
    )
    ,
    cte_Counts   --C
AS 
    (
        SELECT  ProducerCode,ProducerLocationID, 
                COUNT (distinct ControlNo) as Submissions,
                SUM(CASE WHEN QuotedPremium IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Quoted,
                SUM(CASE WHEN  Status = 'Declined' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as  Declined
        FROM    ClearanceReportMetrics
        WHERE   EffectiveDate >=DateAdd(yy, -1, DATEADD(d, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE()))) AND EffectiveDate <= EOMONTH(GETDATE()) AND CompanyLine = 'Plaza Insurance Company'
        GROUP BY ProducerCode,
                ProducerLocationID
    )

SELECT 

            TOP 10 RANK() OVER (ORDER BY NetWrittenPremium desc) as Rank, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.ProducerCode, t.[Producer Location ID] ORDER BY NetWrittenPremium  DESC) as num,           
            t.ProducerCode,
            t.[Producer Location ID],
            t.Producer as ProducerName , 
            NetWrittenPremium, 
            WPNewBusiness,
            WPRenewal, 
            WPRewrite,
            PolicyCount,
            Submissions,
            Quoted,
            BindsNewBusiness,
            BindsRenewals,
            BindsRewrite,
            Declined
FROM        cte_TopWP t INNER JOIN cte_Counts c ON t.ProducerCode=c.ProducerCode and c.ProducerLocationID=t.[Producer Location ID]      
ORDER BY    
            NetWrittenPremium DESC
```

Comment: Does one CTE have a reliable ProducerName?

Comment: well...let say the first cte.

Comment: Thought producername was in second CTE. Since the name is only in the first CTE, I can't see a way find it. Do you have a different table you can use to find the correct name?

Comment: I used `max(Producer`) in  cte_TopWP cte and drop Producer from Group by statement. And it works. Thanks to #SqlZim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use `max(Producer)` in your `cte_TopWP` cte and drop `Producer` from your `Group by` statement.

Comment: Thanks #SqlZim. Works perfectly now. The only thing is I feel embarrassed because it was so easy :)
Thanks again

Comment: This works, but only if the correct one is the max. In this example it is, but is it for all of them?

Comment: That's true, but based on the question it didn't seem like he was looking for a specific one of the two. Alternately you could join to the source `producers` table and pull the name from there after your aggregations in the ctes.

Comment: #jabs, I know what you are saying but yes, for this report from the first `CTE` will be the correct ones. Thanks